# How to use TBB to run a function in a single thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb

I'm trying to use `TBB` to use just one thread to run this piece of code but I do not know how to proceed.

I have read that I should use `tbb::task_group` but I do not know how to use it.

```
void CScene::load(const std::string &_name) {
  if (!references++) {
   setName(_name);
   Resources.setCurrentScene(my_name);

   TEntityParseContext ctx;
   ctx.name = my_name;
   parseScene("data/scenes/" + my_name + ".scene", ctx);

   dynamic = ctx.dynamic_scene;
   for (CHandle e : ctx.entities_loaded) {
     entities.push_back(e);
   }

   Engine.getScriptingModule().raiseEvent(CModuleScripting::SCENE_LOADED, 
   my_name);

   Resources.setCurrentScene("system");
  }
}
```

By the way, entities is a `std::vector<CHandle>` which is a private variable of the class

Comment: I have _no_ idea what this code actually does (because all the relevant contextual information is missing), but is there a reason not to use `std::thread`?

Comment: https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/tutorial-intel-tbb-task-based-programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to pass a lambda to the `task_group::run` function:

```
CScene cs;
tbb::task_group g;

g.run([&cs]{cs.load("Name");});

// maybe do some other work here

// This function either waits or executes the lambda 
// if no other thread is executing it
g.wait();
```